# Is it recommended staying signed in at Stack Exchange sites from a security perspective?

Tags: discussion, login, bountied-tab

Is it recommended staying signed in at Stack Exchange sites from a security perspective? Is there any guide on this or is it recommended to be logged in always on Stack Exchange sites?

I often use it in my home and office. So I am thinking: Should I log out every time before exit?

What is your suggestion or how do you manage this?

Comment: Do you leave your computer on and unlocked? Do other people have ready access to your home or office? Are your coworkers and/or housemates malicious bastards?

Comment: This is a very hard question to answer given the vast parameters surrounding security in general and your own personal setup and scenario. i.e. Do you lend your friend your computer, do others have access to it at all? Do you lock your computer, what OS do you use? Is it a small tech office with like minded security conscious people, or a vast call centre? The list goes on really and is up to you to decide what is secure for you. If others do or could have access when you are away, then I would log out when away for long periods of time.

Comment: Not like that.I lock my desktop.But wanted to know just is it good idea staying logged in

Answer (score 8):

### General strategy for personal computers

This is for machines that ONLY YOU have access to, where this access is protected by strong software and (ideally *also*) physical barriers.

1. Don't worry about it; log in and never ever log out. Make sure you have a valid email address on file just in case you ever *do* get logged out and can't remember your password due to not having logged in in a long time.

### General strategy for shared / public computers

This is for machines that other people have access to regularly.

1. Use a browser that doesn't maintain cookies or other data between sessions (or the "private browsing" mode of a regular browser configuration).
2. Close the browser when you're done and will soon leave the machine unattended.

Comment: Why CW? You plan to make this into a faq or something like that?

Comment: It's one of those days where I'm making a ton of careless mistakes in pretty much everything I write... Instead of editing this one 10 times, figured I'd just invite others.

Comment: So unlike you Shog... kudos! :-)