# Diamond is not shown for mod name under wiki posts

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, community-wiki, moderators

If a diamond mod is an author of a wiki post then the diamond is not displayed besides the mod name. E.g. [Shog9♦'s post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267671/339911):

> [image: Shog9 losing his diamond]

Even when the name refers to the user profile page (in case of more then one author) like in [another post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237978/339911):

> [image: Still no diamond here]

Is it intentional or a bug?

Comment: I think it's intentional. Note that the link doesn't lead to Shog's profile, but rather to the revisions page.

Comment: @Glorfindel this is [another bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253972/339911).

Comment: [meta-tag:status-bydesign] in 3... 2... 1...

Comment: Why does it matter? The idea of wikis is community collaboration so if anything the diamond not being displayed is better so it doesn't look like an official answer and it welcomes community edits.

Comment: @PeterJ mods can answer his own answers, i.e. not "official". Should the diamond be hidden in such cases according to your logic?

Comment: Thinking further yes it probably should be, even for a community elected mod it's a sign they are not sure about the answer so the fact they are a mod shouldn't influence others in whether to edit it. Just edited to add - I'm only talking about wiki posts, not all answers.

Comment: Haha. It's [meta-tag:status-bydesign] now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think this is a bug, but rather they did it fully on purpose.

The diamond, in this case, is not relevant. For Community Wiki posts, the author is not really relevant, so there are also no other details, just the name. No reputation, no badges, no user card.

If someone wants to see details about the author(s) of a wiki post, they can just click the link and see the full revisions list, where the diamond is showing just fine:

> [image: screenshot of revisions page with Shog's diamond]

Note that unlike ordinary posts, even without any edits, the author name is link to revisions, so they are always one click away, no need to manually change URL like in the case of ordinary post without edits.

Comment: "No reputation, no badges, no user card" ... obvious continue is "no user name". But name is here. And I think it should refrect the user status. Also look for the post update.

Comment: @alexolut well, I'll support feature request asking to remove that percentage and user name, true. It's often wrong and quite useless. But yet again, this is not a bug.

Comment: I'll wait for mod (6-8 weeks) to change the question tags :) Because I still think it's a buggy behaviour.

Comment: @alexolut well, Shog just did.

Comment: Seems I need to change the images in my question to another mod.

Comment: Do you know what's going on? Too much upvotes for old posts on the single day.

Comment: Yeah, turns out similar post was made today on MSO and someone linked to this one.

Comment: I completely forgot about MSO, only checked linked questions on this page, and didn't found anything new.

Comment: I think the consequent behavior of the software would still dictate if the diamond would be shown, although it is only a cosmetical issue.