# Suggestion: don't show diamond on main site posts of moderators

Tags: feature-request, moderators

It is mildly bothering me that on main site questions and answers of moderators the user name is shown with the diamond. I can see how reputation is relevant to be displayed, as it says something about the value of the content of the post, but the moderator diamond is only an indirect indicator of someone's expertise. (I'm a moderator myself and feel some unease that my posts are distinguished, even if only so slightly.) So I'd like to suggest here to remove the diamond on main site posts.

I *do* see the usefulness of the diamond on main site comments and meta questions, answers, and comments, of course.

There is a precedent for this: the [diamond is already hidden on community wiki posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305546/205264).

Comment: Aren't you asked in the candidate questionnaire, "a moderator diamond will be attached to all your prior posts, what do you think"?

Comment: @SonictheBracketedHedgehog that questionnaire is not carved in stone...

Comment: The questionnaire is not set in stone, but it's a good thing to keep in mind right now.  If anything, I'd take a page out of Reddit's playbook and allow mods to post as such, or as a regular user.  That would complicate the process quite a bit, though.

Comment: On a couple SE sites, I've long witnessed widespread reluctance of many regular users to even so much as  downvote a not-okay answer posted by a mod, let alone critique it. Many users erroneously believe that the mod can see who downvoted their post.   I'm just saying, I support this idea on main sites, so the diamond does not intimidate regular users from  downvoting or critiquing a mod's post, and doesn't encourage users to upvote and/or praise it only because a mod posted it.